# form_dropdown css class not work at codeigniter

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

i try to set a style to a form_dropdown of codeigniter but is not wokrk. my code is:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('week_id',$weeklist,'class ="form-control selectpicker"'); ?>
```

Also i try to use the html code with this class and work prefect so my external links of .css and .js are true.  Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

leave third argument empty.Put class in 4th argument it will work.

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('week_id',$weeklist,'','class ="form-control selectpicker"'); ?>
```

3rd argument is to pre select a value in select box and 4th is to add id and class etc. Refer [Here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html)

`form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'large', $js)`;